# A complete and opentype cyrillic font

Tags: fonts, cyrillic

I am currently looking for a cyrillic font (for russian typewritting). It must be an opentype font usable with `lualatex` and `fontspec`, and must be complete : roman, italic, bold, small caps, superiors letters and figures, in serif and sans serif.
For all I know, Libertinus is very close, but it lacks cyrillic small caps and superior cyrillic letters.
Does a more complete font exist?

Comment: Hm, I know [Alegreya Sans (SC)](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Alegreya+Sans+SC) and Serif (SC) both of which have Cyrillic small caps (in separate small caps fonts). I don't know about Cyrillic superscript letters though. Or you could combine fonts, like [Cormorant](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cormorant) (a serif font) and [Ysabeau](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Ysabeau) (a sans-serif font), again with separate SC fonts, which go quite well together. Otherwise, I think, you should look for super families provided by the large font foundries, but they have their price.

Comment: Anyways, I fear, this question is not directly related to TeX and rather a font question since you could use any OpenType font with LuaLaTeX. So, it might be considered off-topic on this site.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  I asked this question in order to use fonts with LaTeX, but it is true that it is not related to LaTeX, I should have thought about it.  What are the actual places where I could ask such questions?

Comment: You could (maybe in addition to your question here) ask over at https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com . But leave your question here as well. Even if it is not 100% on-topic, someone here might have an answer. I won't close it, I only warn you about this.

Comment: Charis SIL (fonts.sil.org) seems to come close, only you'll have to build the OpenType version yourself from font sources (https://github.com/silnrsi/font-charis). As it is, it's distributed as TTF.

Comment: Very few fonts, even for the Latin alphabet, have a full complement of alphabetic superscripts.  You will be better off making sure that the other features you need are well taken care of.  Superscripts can be provided by a suitable macro definition.